# add a $ sign infront of all textbox on the page

Tags: javascript

I have a page that displays alot of values in different text boxes. However right now I want to write a javascript that adds a $ sign infront of all the textboxes. This is what I have in mind

```
function addDollarSign() {
   var inputValue = document.getElementById("textBoxName").value;

   if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0)
   {
      inputValue = "$" + inputValue;
   }

   document.getElementById("textBoxName").value = inputValue;
}
```

However This would only work for 1 specific case. 
But How do I add a $sign to every single textbox on the page without constantly duplicating the same code

Comment: There's no good reason why you'd need to do this on the client side. Do it on the server side, and then people without JavaScript can have the same experience.

Comment: if you just want to show it as a currency information, then don't add it in textbox, show it as text outside textbox using html in a span tag for example else you may have problems in processing those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop thru them:

```
var inputElementList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputElementList.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = inputElementsList[i];
    currentElement.value = '$' + currentElement.value;
}
```

- Get an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements with [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)
- Loop thru them with `i` starting at `0` going up to the `.length` of your [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)
- Get the current element with array-style indexes
- Add `'$'` to the value

Answer (score 1):

For your current requirement, it would be better to add the "$" sign in the server side itself.

Anyhow here is a script to add "$" sign inside the textbox

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input') will return you a NodeList.
```

So you must iterate it to add the "$" sign.

```
var inputNodeList= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var element in inputNodeList) {
    var inputElement = inputNodeList[element];
    inputElement.value = '$' + inputElement.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having little problem understanding you code but the solution sounds with surrounding the code with for loop.

```
for(int i = 0, i <document.length, i++){

     var inputValue = document.getElementById("textBoxName").value;

       if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0)
       {
          inputValue = "$" + inputValue;
       }
    }
```